# How to enable USB debugging on a wiped device?

Tags: rom-flashing, boot-loop, usb-debugging

Device name : MI A1
USB debugging is not enabled and wiped the Dalvik/Cache, Data etc. 
Now the phone just bootloops to MI loading screen. Please suggest a work around.

So basically there is no OS. I am not able to flash a ROM since there's no USB Debugging.

Comment: it is not possible to flash via usb-debugging (and therefore not required). btw if you see loading screen the OS is still present. just format userdata and wait up to 15 min on first boot. if you modified any partitions (for example flashed TWRP) you must install [no-verity-opt-encrypt-6.1.zip](https://build.nethunter.com/android-tools/no-verity-opt-encrypt) to disable dm-verity

Comment: usb-debugging = adb. adb is not used for flashing firmware. Flashing is done via fastboot or via a recovery ROM like TWRP. In a recovery adb can only be used to transferring the image data to the device (adb sideloading), but TWRP is the software that flashes it.

Comment: Thank you guys. That helped me a lot ! I was somehow able to access internal storage and flashed a stock ROM.